# Why are CO₂ diffusors supposed to be located far from water movement?

Tags: aquarium, water-parameters, equipment

My Dennerle Profi-Line CO<sub>2</sub> Diffusor recommends to place it far from water movement, e.g. the filter output, but when I put it there I see that the fine CO<sub>2</sub> bubbles which take about 15 seconds to rise to the water surface, where a part of them still isn't dissolved completely in the water, are pushed down by the water stream and almost all dissolve.

I already have placed the filter output quite far below the surface in order to reduce water surface moving which reduces the CO<sub>2</sub> level into the water.

I have a 60 l freshwater aquarium.